# How do I make ansible.builtin.lineinfile task indempotent?

Tags: regex, ansible

I am working on an Ansible task that is meant to search for a line in a file and update that line if necessary. However my task is not indempotent in that the more times I run it the more times my line addition gets added to the end of the line. How do I avoid this? Here is my task:

```
- name: Enable libvirt_guest dns via nss
  ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
    path: /etc/nsswitch.conf
    regex: ^(hosts:.*)
    line: \1 libvirt_guest
    backrefs: true
  become: true
```

I want to be able to run this task over and over and never get libvirt_guest to appear on the line more than once. However with this task I get an extra libvirt_guest added to the end of the line every time I run the playbook that pulls in this task.

Comment: Please read [ask] and pay attention to the [mre] section. Then [edit] your question with an example file you are modifying, the exact result you get and the one you expect instead.

Answer (score 3):

If this is the use case where you want to be sure that some sources are present in specific databases you might want to use a *template* instead of a tricky regular expression in *lineinfile*. The [man nsswitch.con](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nsswitch.conf.5.html) says:

> '...The file is plain ASCII text, with **columns separated by spaces or tab** characters.  The first column specifies the database name. The remaining columns describe the order of sources to query ...'

For example, let's test it in the default Ubuntu /etc/nsswitch.conf

```yaml
shell> cat /etc/nsswitch.conf 
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         files systemd
group:          files systemd
shadow:         files
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mymachines
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

1. Declare variables below. The variable *nsswitch_conf* keeps the current content of the file and *nsswitch_conf_add* is a dictionary of items(sources) to be added to the keys(databases)

```yaml
    nsswitch_conf: "{{ nsswitch.content|b64decode|from_yaml }}"
    nsswitch_conf_add:
      hosts: [libvirt_guest]
```

2. Read the current configuration

```yaml
    - slurp:
        src: /etc/nsswitch.conf
      register: nsswitch
```

gives

```yaml
  nsswitch_conf:
    ethers: db files
    group: files systemd
    gshadow: files
    hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mymachines
    netgroup: nis
    networks: files
    passwd: files systemd
    protocols: db files
    rpc: db files
    services: db files
    shadow: files
```

3. Create the template

```yaml
shell> cat nsswitch.conf.j2
{% for k,v in nsswitch_conf.items() %}
{% set key = k ~ ':' %}
{% set val = (v.split() + nsswitch_conf_add[k]|d([]))|unique|join(' ') %}
{{ '{}{}'.format(key.ljust(16), val) }}
{% endfor %}
```

and update the configuration

```yaml
    - template:
        src: nsswitch.conf.j2
        dest: /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

By running the playbook with '--check --diff' options you can see that the comments and blank lines will be removed and the additional source *libvirt_guest* will be added to *hosts*.

```yaml
TASK [template] ******************************************************************************
--- before: /etc/nsswitch.conf
+++ after: /home/vlado/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1049632a310sjg/tmpi7is2j3v/nsswitch.conf.j2
@@ -1,20 +1,11 @@
-# /etc/nsswitch.conf
-#
-# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
-# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
-# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.
-
 passwd:         files systemd
 group:          files systemd
 shadow:         files
 gshadow:        files
-
-hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mymachines
+hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mymachines libvirt_guest
 networks:       files
-
 protocols:      db files
 services:       db files
 ethers:         db files
 rpc:            db files
-
 netgroup:       nis
```

---

**Notes**

1. Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    nsswitch_conf: "{{ nsswitch.content|b64decode|from_yaml }}"
    nsswitch_conf_add:
      hosts: [libvirt_guest]

  tasks:

    - slurp:
        src: /etc/nsswitch.conf
      register: nsswitch
    - debug:
        var: nsswitch_conf
    - template:
        src: nsswitch.conf.j2
        dest: /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

2. The order of sources matters. If you want to prepend the source change this line in the template

```yaml
{% set val = (nsswitch_conf_add[k]|d([]) + v.split())|unique|join(' ') %}
```

gives

```yaml
-hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mymachines
+hosts:          libvirt_guest files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mymachines
```

3. You can define the index of the source. For example, make sure the source *libvirt_guest* is second in the list. Declare the variable

```yaml
    nsswitch_conf_add:
      hosts: [1, libvirt_guest]
```

and add the logic in the template

```yaml
shell> cat nsswitch.conf.j2
{% for k,v in nsswitch_conf.items() %}
{% set key = k ~ ':' %}
{% if nsswitch_conf_add[k] is defined %}
{% set i = nsswitch_conf_add[k] %}
{% set arr = v.split() %}
{% set val = (arr[:i.0] + [i.1] + arr[i.0:])|unique|join(' ') %}
{% else %}
{% set val = v %}
{% endif %}
{{ '{}{}'.format(key.ljust(16), val) }}
{% endfor %}
```

gives

```yaml
-hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mymachines
+hosts:          files libvirt_guest mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mymachines
```

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up doing this which seems to work well and is pretty simple.

```
- name: Check for libvirt_guest in nsswitch.conf
  ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
    path: /etc/nsswitch.conf
    regex: ^hosts:.*libvirt_guest*
    state: absent
  check_mode: true
  changed_when: false
  register: libvirt_guest
  become: false

- name: Enable libvirt_guest dns via nss
  ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
    path: /etc/nsswitch.conf
    regex: ^(hosts:.*)
    line: \1 libvirt_guest
    backrefs: true
  become: true
  when: not libvirt_guest.found
```